# Why do views cover up things below them, but not above?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm not sure why if I place a button on the top of a LinearLayout and then a view below it I can see the button. However, if I place the button below the view the view covers it up.

For example with the button on top everything is visible:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But if you place the button below the view you can only see the view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why is this? How can I get a view to not wrap over things placed below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get a view to not wrap over things placed below it?

By giving your `View` a height. The

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

tag definition is ambiguous and cannot be rendered. It looks like Android is turning this into

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

And is thus pushing your `Button` outside the window.

Comment: So it's just pushing the button off the screen and not actually covering it up? I don't want to assign my view a fixed height. I just want it to fill the top without pushing things off the bottom. Any ideas?

Comment: Android to Josh: When you say 'fill the top', you are talking about filling the screen horizontally, right? How do you want it to behave vertically? You can consider hardcoding a value there, or setting it at runtime if you need to, but setting a height is required. You can consider using margins on your Button if this achieves what you need.

Comment: Well I learned it's pushing the button down and not covering it up. I manually set the height and then it didn't push it down. So I'll just have to do that or handle it better at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Its because Your view is custom view and root of all layouts/views such as LinaerLayout,Relative Layout,Table Layout,Absolute Layout .So chicld iew (Linear Layout in your case cannot put constraint on view ), and your custom view here has not till now decided yet its width and height  BUt if  you make it custom in some class and give its width and height in onMeasure then at runtime button will come below of it .